# Macro class without repeat

Tags: c++, macros

I use a lot of class with different name but the base is always same

For example :

```
class MyScript : public MyClass
{
    public:
        MyScript() : MyClass("MyScript") { }

    /* My Functions */
};

void Register()
{
    new MyScript();
}
```

it's possible to create for example a macro for avoid duplicate in my class? For example

```
class MyScript : public MyClass
{
    /* My Functions */
};

void Register()
{
    RegisterScript(MyScript);
}
```

RegisterScript is there macro that write

```
public:
    MyScript() : MyClass("MyScript") { }
```

Thanks for your answers

Comment: Your `Register` function does memleak...

Comment: Is it possible? Yes, though depending on how much exactly you need to generate there may be better alternatives. What have you tried doing?

Comment: Inheritance seems remove your duplication here.

Comment: I don't think you are using the word macro in the correct manner.  This means something a bit different than from what you describe.  Perhaps if you had more sample code to describe your issue?

Comment: `void Register()
{
    new MyScript();
}` - this is a memory leak

Comment: Do not use `operator new`. It is toxic.

Comment: @EdHeal I think `MyScript::MyScript` is adding the object to some global list, which has its own problems, but a memory leak is not one of them.

Comment: @immibis exactly, only functions inside can cause problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your default constructors will do nothing other than instantiate the base class, you can do the following:

```
#define RegisterScript(Type) Type() : MyClass(#Type) { }
```

This is an example of a macro with parameters the argument here is the derived class type. However, this macro has to be called *inside* the class. Setting constructors outside the class doesn't make much sense anyways.

[[GCC]](https://wandbox.org/permlink/VUnYYbBztPlbqkGO)

Comment: Yes exactly my base class are on instantiate. It's not a good idea to put public directly in macro ? Thanks for your help !

Comment: Yes, you should definitely not put visibility specifiers in your macros.